# SharePoint 2013 - disposing SP.ClientContext in JavaScript

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, dispose

I'm little bit confused about JS's COM in SharePoint 2013 and disposing ClientContext object.
As far as I can see from earlier versions of SP (2010 mainly) you had to dispose ClientContext and according to MSDN there is a method on this object called Dispose. However, when I'm trying to dispose ClientContext object, I got error that object doesn't have this method. Also, IntelliSense is not exposing it.

The question is - in SharePoint 2013 in client object model (used in JavaScript), do I have to dispose ClientContext (either initialized as new SP.ClientContext(url) or SP.ClientContext.get_current() ), and if I do, how and when?

Comment: You had to dispose the JavaScript object in 2010? Are you sure? Got any link to that? However `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext` extends `IDisposable` and you should dispose this, but only in C#, I imagine this will dispose off some TCP clients

Comment: @eirikb I've never worked with SP2010, but I got feeling you had to Dispose ClientContext from an article or two which I read. I might, indeed, be wrong.

Comment: Have you seen http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/62902/627 ? This question might be a duplicate, as I believe it should be the same for 2013.

Comment: @eirikb (and MdMazzoti) - yep, that Q&As are what I was looking for. Thanks!